# listview iframe inside modal - have links open over parent

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I tried to search for a solution and found a few on here but nothing relating to listview,

I have a dispform that includes an iframe showing a related list, the problem is that all the links from the listview open a popup inside the iframe which is very small so I am trying to have them open ontop of the parent.

I tried using base target which seems to work for custom urls and even the add new button, but any link from the list itself still opens inside the iframe window

I am using Sharepoint and SPD 2010